# Mysql - how to strip certain characters from the end of the string

Tags: mysql, regex, str-replace

I have strings like this :

```
column:
----------
word[1]   
word[2]     
word   
word[2]   
word    
word[3]
```

Where **word** is a variable length random characters string.
How would I remove square brackets with numbers in them from the end of these strings in mysql table?
Does mysql allow regexes?

Comment: its just for display ? or u want to update in the table ?

Comment: Putting absolutely no effort into figuring this out yourself, I will refer you to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) which is the first google result for "mysql regex".

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty updating the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update test 
set name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,'[',1)
where name=name
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0182/1)**

Comment: Why do we need 'where name=name' ? It seems irrelevant is it not?

Comment: sorry I was wrong no need to have where condition u r right.http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5702c/1

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following select:

```
IF(RIGHT[(myColumn, 1) = "]", SUBSTRING(myColumn, -3), myColumn)
```

RIGHT(mycolumn, 1) == ] will check if your entry lasts with a closing bracket.
SUBSTRING(myColumn, -3) will return the string without the closing bracket, if there is one.
myColumns will return the full string, if there is no bracket.